# how to get 3rd level sub category in Top menu Opencart v2.3

Tags: php, html, css, opencart, opencart2.x

I tried all the steps other similar previous questions but it didnt worked. I want to get 3rd level sub category in  Top menu Opencart  v2.3

This below code is of 2levelcategory, I need to create 3level category.
This is the header.php file code

```
$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category['top']) {
            // Level 2
            $children_data = array();

            $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $filter_data = array(
                    'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                    'filter_sub_category' => true
                );

                $children_data[] = array(
                    'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                );
            }

            // Level 1
            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'     => $category['name'],
                'children' => $children_data,
                'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
            );
        }
    }
```

This is the header.tpl file code

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-inner">
          <?php foreach (array_chunk($category['children'], ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column'])) as $children) { ?>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <?php foreach ($children as $child) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="see-all"><?php echo $text_all; ?> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></a> </div>
    </li>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Add 3rd level of categories like this:
controller file:

```
    $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category['top']) {
            // Level 2
            $children_data = array();

            $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

            foreach ($children as $child) {
                // Level 3
                $grandchildren_data = array();

                $grandchildren = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child['category_id']);

                foreach ($grandchildren as $grandchild) {

                    $grandchild_filter_data = array(
                        'filter_category_id'  => $grandchild['category_id'],
                        'filter_sub_category' => true
                    );

                    $grandchildren_data[] = array(
                        'name'  => $grandchild['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($grandchild_filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $grandchild['category_id'])
                    );
                }

                $filter_data = array(
                    'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                    'filter_sub_category' => true
                );

                $children_data[] = array(
                    'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']),
                    'children' => $grandchildren_data,
                );
            }

            // Level 1
            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'     => $category['name'],
                'children' => $children_data,
                'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
            );
        }
    }
```

view file:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <div class="dropdown-inner">
                  <?php foreach (array_chunk($category['children'], ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column'])) as $children) { ?>
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <?php foreach ($children as $child) { ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
                        <?php if($child['children']){ ?>
                            <ul>
                                <?php foreach ($child['children'] as $child) { ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a></li>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </ul>
                  <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="see-all"><?php echo $text_all; ?> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></a> </div>
            </li>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
```

I've tested my work on opencart 2.3.0.2 with default theme:
[image: Opencart 2 3rd category level]